# Mahout CSV to SEQ for text vectorization

Tags: csv, vectorization, mahout

I have a large CSV file where each line consists (id, description) in a Text format. I wanted to convert each line to a vector using "seq2sparse" and then later run "rowsimilarity" to generate a textual similarity result.

Problem is i need to convert the CSV file to SEQ somehow to work with "seq2sparse", and existing method "seqdirectory" takes a directory of text files rather than a CSV file. Anyway to accomplish this?